# Activate or deactivate the sliders in slider revolution

Tags: plugins

I have a slider revolution where in there are four revolution sliders.

Now the current scenario is the 2nd slider is been activated, but i want to deactivate the 2nd slider and activate first slider

The screenshot is shown below
[image: Screenshots]

In the above screen shot #3 Retrax video is activated but i need #1 Mainslider to be activate

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. A SLIDER is made of 1 or many slides. You use a slider by pasting its shortcode into a page. You do not activate/desactivate sliders. You just use them or don't. Your screenshot shows SLIDERS, not SLIDES.

If you talk about activating/desactivating one or several slides into a slider, you must edit the slider you target. It will show all slides in it. Just click the small top icon on the slide you want to disable. It will turn to a Forbidden red icon. Your slider will still display other slides. You may drag and drop slides to order them and so else.

Revolution Slider is not easy to master. Read documentation intensively. Otherwise, look for simplier Sliders plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to select a different slider than the current one from within your page settings. That is, open the WordPress page that has the slider, and in the "Slideshow Options" select one of the other sliders from the "Choose Slider" dropdown menu.